# Is there any advantage to using AWS Traffic Flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I need to implement a rather complex GSLB system to support every country/state/continent worldwide. I found AWS has a service called Traffic Flow, but creating a Traffic Flow policy costs $50/month each (I'll need to have more than one). Is there any extra functionality derived from Traffic Flow that I couldn't achieve by manually implementing all of the necessary route53 record set boto3 calls to create the same policy? Is the $50/month just for ease of use?

Comment: There are two ways of interpreting this question.  One ("Is this worth what it costs?") seems primarily opinion based and subject to closure of the question as off-topic. The other ("The price of this service seems out of line with the functionality it seems to offer, and this leads me to assume that perhaps I have misunderstood what it actually does, or how it works.  What is the technical difference between this, and a complex-but-manual configuration?") might be considered less subjective by this community.  If the latter is intended, then you may wish to edit the question, to clarify.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I believe believe both are the same question under the hood, the high cost belies some technical aspect I believe I'm missing. I'm incredulous. The real question is what is the difference. The shock value comes from the high cost.

Comment: I agree, it's essentially the same fundamental question either way, but "is it worth it?" *sounds* subjective and discussion-oriented, while "how is it different?" seems more like an objective question with a correct answer. I didn't want to see your (valid, in my mind) question closed as "off-topic, primarily opinion based" if too many people saw it as the former.